# Where to get fonts for fictional ancient languages?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, languages, mage-the-awakening, fonts

I'm starting a Mage: The Awakening chronicle and I would like to present my players with messages and letters occasionally written in ancient scripts (fictional ones, i.e. Lemurean, Atlantean and similar). However, I have trouble finding suitable fonts for writing such texts.

Where should I look for scripts that fit our game before hunting through obscure google results?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### [Omniglot](http://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/atlantean.htm)

The writers for Disney's Atlantis, Klingon from Star trek, etc. All created languages during the course of their creations, and most of them are available on this site, called Omniglot. At the bottom of some Omniglot pages there are fictional fonts that you can use for writing that should fit what you're looking for. Personally my favorite is the Daedric alphabet from The Elder Scrolls games, but there are a lot of languages and fonts to browse on this site.

For a nice overview of fonts available from Omniglot, see its [fonts page](http://omniglot.com/fonts/index.htm).

---

### [Dieter](http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/steffmann/index.htm)

Dieter is a website made by Dieter Steffmann that hosts a wide variety of fonts. While I personally don't feel that it has a lot of fantasy fonts similar to Omniglot, its selection of fonts covers a wide variety of text types and is worthy of mentioning as well.

Thanks to @Storyteller for the suggestion.

Comment: I was bored enough in high school that I took most of my notes in daedric.... actually, that persisted into college, too, for some classes.

Comment: Daedric = Best alphabet

Comment: I used to write a lot of notes using the Tolkenized version of Futhark runes. Then I invented my own. They're handy when you want to express your opinions of people without actually letting them know how you feel.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

As for Daedric, yes, it is usable, but too easy and weel-known to use for hidden text (at least in my trope).

Answer (score 9):

I often use different fonts in player handouts. My preferred tool to find them is Google. I've found some nice fonts from Fontspace.com, Dafont.com,  and 1001freefonts.com.

For example, a font I am using in an upcoming game:

- http://www.dafont.com/deadspace.font

For example, some Forgotten Realms fonts:

- http://www.fonts2u.com/dethek--dwarvish-fr.font
- http://www.fonts2u.com/espruar-elvish-fr.font
- http://www.fontspace.com/pixel-sagas/dethek-stone
- http://www.fonts2u.com/thorass-normal.font
- http://www.1001freefonts.com/thorass.font

For example, Tolkein rune fonts:

- http://www.fonts2u.com/angerthas-moria.font
- http://www.fontspace.com/bruce-kvam/angerthas

It is worth downloading the same font from multiple places, as different authors might have included different glyphs in their fonts. This is particularly important if you want punctuation - many authors don't include marks like periods, commas or hyphens.